# In 802.11, is it possible to send authentication request packets from a device to the access point without sending probe requests?

Tags: authentication, wifi, probe

I am trying to send authentication requests from several spoofed mac addresses to the AP. When I ran wireshark, I was able to see authentication responses from the AP. But how is this possible as no probe requests packets have been sent from these spoofed mac addresses.

This looks like this is stateless. But from what I have read, I have understand, there are three states -

1. Unauthenticated, Unassociated
2. Authenticated, Unassociated
3. Authenticated, Associated

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the answer is "Yes, it is possible to send authentication request packets without sending probe requests".

As far as I know, Probe Requests are only necessary to allow mobile devices to obtain information from the APs at will (i.e. instead of waiting for beacons).